# How to create a relationship across three models in laravel-4?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following data structure:

```
 Table t:
      (PK)id
          order_id (this links to table or's id)


 Table is:
      (PK)id
          tracking_id (this links to table or's tracking_id)

 Table or:
      (PK)id    (this links to table t's order_id)
      (FK)tracking_id
```

Now inside my model (T.php)

I set the following relationship:

```
 public function iS()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('is', 'tracking_id', 'order_id');
 }
```

Now obviously this doesn't work because tracking_id is not a match to order_id.

How do I link these three tables together so that I can retrieve the `is` data that corresponds to the `t` table?

I'm calling it this inside my Controller:

```
  $o = O::with('t', 't.iS')->where('id','=',$id)->first(); (O is my model for "o" table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for hasManyThrough relationship.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#has-many-through

In the documentation example: `Country` has `Users` and `Users` have `Posts`.
To get posts of each country you define:

```
class Country extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Post', 'User', 'country_id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

In your example: `T` has `Or` and `Or` has `Is`

Comment: @neinI saw the example, I tried doing it inside my T so it looked like this:

 `return $this->hasManyThrough('Or','Is')` Didn't work correctly. Am I creating the relationship inside the wrong Model?

Comment: You need to do `$this->hasManyThrough('Is','Or');`

Comment: Also, you need to manually specify the relationship keys. (since the default eloquent expects `or_id` and `is_id`). Deriving from the documentation example, I think you need to do `$this->hasManyThrough('Is','Or','id','tracking_id');`